# How to check whether selected node is having child nodes or not in jstree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I m taking selected node by following code.

```
var selected=$("#warehouseTree").jstree('get_selected');
```

and now i want to check for child nodes for selected node.

Answer (score 5):

This is simply how you extract children information from a specific node.

```js
$("#tree_2").jstree().get_node("13").children
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var tree = jQuery.jstree._reference('#warehouseTree');
var children = tree._get_children(selected);
```

Which will return an array of jQuery objects of the children of the selected node.

Answer (score 1):

this will help.

```
   if(selected.children().size() > 0)
    {
    //has child
    }
```

Comment: This won't work as selected will be an <li> element, which in jstree will always have a child <a> element, therefore the above code will always return true.

Comment: What worked for me was if(selected.children.length >0)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check whether a node has children or not.

```
var tree = jQuery.jstree._reference('#warehouseTree');
var isParent = instance.is_parent(selected);
console.log(isParent) //  true for directory
```